# How do I get a JSON record with a specific ID with Angular AjAX?

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax

I have this function in my service

```
   function getSomeData() {
  return $http
    .get('/someData.json')
    .then(itWorked)
    .catch(onFail);
```

That returns all the records from that JSON file.  What If I want just a single record for which I have the ID?  This seems like it would be a simple search, but I'm coming up empty.

Comment: This depends on the server what it is returning. Also you are requesting the entire JSON file `someData.json`, so you will have to extract your required data in your `.then` block as answered by @Josh. But you want to send the `ID` in your request and expect the single record based on that, then its server side code and not client side. An end-point at server required to handle the request and respond only the single record that belongs to this ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an array you can certainly write your own find function:

```
var foundItem;
data.forEach(function(item){
   if(item === someId){
      foundItem = item;
   }
});
```

Or better yet, if you are using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#find) *(which I highly recommend)*, you can do it  in one line:

```
var foundItem = _.find(data, {id: someId});
```

Comment: I had that approach in mind, but thought of it as the "big hammer" approach.  Is there not some SQL type syntax like a where clause that can be used?

Comment: @ebick - You mean within your AJAX request? No nothing like that. You get the whole JSON resource back. If you need more fine grained control, you will have to either create a web service, or wrap it in an Angular service.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be using the $filter service to filter the record from the list.

```
var filterSelectedRecordFromList = function(
    objectArray, expr) {
    var filtered = $filter('filter')(objectArray,expr,true);
        return filtered[0];
};
```

so in your case if the call the filterSelectedRecordFromList like below..
where data is the JSON list and someID is the Id that you want to search.

```
var filteredRecord = filterSelectedRecordFromList(data,{id:someId},true);
```